# Split and get last part of a string in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have string like "abc-def-gef". I need to remove the first part of the string from "-" and get the last part like "def-gef". How its possible in c#. Please help me to find out the solution.

Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried? One way: `String.Join("-", str.Split('-').Skip(1))`

Comment: [Regex example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0YQA99)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

here:

```
string str = "abc-def-gef";
str = str.Substring(str.IndexOf("-")+1);
```

`IndexOf("-")` will return the index of the first "-" and `Substring` will cut the string from that index (+1 to skip "-") to the end of the string

Answer (score 14):

This is a simple way I would do it if you always want the last one and the delimeter is always '-'.

```
var myString =  "abc-def-gef";

var result = myString.Split('-').Last();
```

Output: "gef"

```
var result2 = myString.Split('-').Skip(1).Take(2);
```

Output : An IEnumerable of "gef" "def"

Comment: The `Take(2)` is unnecessary, simply `Skip(1)` will already give an enumerable until the end.  Also, since OP seems to want the ending left joined together, there's an overload of Split that allows you to specify the number of results (it will stop looking for delimiters): `myString.Split(new[] { '-' }, 2)` will return `{ "abc", "def-gef" }`

Answer (score 3):

As Alex said, you can use `Substring` in combination with `LastIndexOf`

```
    var str = "abc-def-gef";
    var newStr = str.Substring(str.LastIndexOf("-") + 1); //returns gef
```

or

```
    var str = "abc-def-gef";
    var newStr = str.Substring(str.IndexOf("-") + 1); //returns def-gef
```

Answer (score -1):

something like this. Please correct syntax for the same:

```
string inpt = "abc-def-gef";
string[] arr = inp.Split('-');
string result = arr[1] + "-" +arr[2];
```